# Minimum of the given expression

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima, quadratic-programming

> For all real numbers $a$ and $b$ find the minimum of the following expression.
>   $$(a-b)^2 + (2-a-b)^2 + (2a-3b)^2$$

I tried expressing the entire expression in terms of a single function of $a$ and $b$. For example, if the entire expression reduces to $(a-2b)^2+(a-2b)+5$ then its minimum can be easily found. But nothing seems to get this expression in such a form, because of the third unsymmetric square.

Since there are two variables here we can also not use differentiation.

Can you please provide hints on how to solve this?

Comment: Hint : First check whether all the paranthesis can be $0$. If yes, the global minimum must be $0$. Unfortunately, this is not the case here.

Comment: what kind of numbers are $a,b$?

Comment: You can use differentiation. Try using partial derivative.

Comment: @MCCCS Can we solve it without using partial derivatives? We haven't been taught that.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+(a-b)%5E2%2B(2-a-b)%5E2%2B(2a-3b)%5E2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
(a-b)^2+(2-a-b)^2+(2a-3b)^2=6a^2-12ab+11b^2-4(a+b)+4 \\
=6\left(a-b-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2+5\left(b-\frac{4}{5}\right)^2+\color{red}{\frac{2}{15}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How did you get the idea that the expression can be written in form of these two squares. I tried a lot of arrangements but couldn't form these two squares.

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit There is a mistake in your solution. See my proof. It's right!

Comment: @Eloise The first term is obtained from completing the square for $a$, so that you're only left with constant terms and terms in powers of $b$. Then you complete the square for $b$, and this leaves you with a constant term, which must be the minimum value. By setting each of the squared terms to zero, you can then find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit The mistake Michael Rozenberg refers to is in the LHS of the first line - you've mis-transcribed the last term, which was $(2a-3b)^{2}$ as opposed to $(2a+3b)^{2}$. The expansion and subsequent steps are correct though.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg ... well spotted ... edit now ...Thanks.

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit At least do you understand that our solutions are the same?

Comment: Eloise as @T.Linnell says ... the first bracket deals with the $a$'s ...$6(a-b-1/3)^2+5b^2-8b+10/3$ ... now complete the square for $b$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $a=\frac{17}{15}$ and $b=\frac{4}{5}$.

Hence, we get a value $\frac{2}{15}$.

Thus, it remains to prove that
$$(a-b)^2 + (2-a-b)^2 + (2a-3b)^2\geq\frac{2}{15}$$ or
$$10(3a-3b-1)^2+3(5b-4)^2\geq0$$
Done!

I got my solution by the following way.

We need to find a maximal $k$ for which the following inequality is true for all reals $a$, $b$ and $c$.
$$(a-b)^2 + (2-a-b)^2 + (2a-3b)^2\geq k$$ or
$$6a^2-4(3b+1)a+11b^2-4b+4-k\geq0,$$ for which we need
$$4(3b+1)^2-6(11b^2-4b+4-k)\leq0$$ or
$$15b^2-24b+10-3k\geq0,$$
for which we need $$12^2-15(10-3k)\leq0$$ or
$$k\leq\frac{2}{15}.$$
The equality occurs for $k=\frac{2}{15}$, $b=\frac{24}{2\cdot15}$, which is $b=\frac{4}{5}$ and for these values we obtain
$$(a-b)^2 + (2-a-b)^2 + (2a-3b)^2\geq \frac{2}{15}$$ it's
$$6a^2-4(3b+1)a+11b^2-4b+4-\frac{2}{15}\geq0$$ or
$$90a^2-60(3b+1)a+165b^2-60b+58\geq0$$ or
$$10(9a^2-6(3b+1)a+(3b+1)^2)-10(3b+1)^2+165b^2-60b+58\geq0$$ or
$$10(3a-3b-1)^2+75b^2-120b+48\geq0$$ or
$$10(3a-3b-1)^2+3(5a-4)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: You're starting with the answer though. That doesn't really help OP to solve the problem, all it does is verify that $a=\frac{17}{15}, b=\frac{4}{5}$ is the solution.

Comment: @T. Linnell See better my solution, please. My solution it's exactly like Donald Splutterwit wrote, but I made it before and without mistakes.

Comment: You're starting from $a=\frac{17}{15}, b=\frac{4}{5}$ with no explanation of how you've chosen these values. Your solution is correct, and you *did* post it first, but as written, it only solves the problem, without really explaining *how* to.

Comment: @T. Linnell I just proved the quadratic inequality. Should be $\Delta\leq0$ and from here we can get the equality case $a=\frac{17}{5}$ and $b=\frac{4}{5}$. I think Donald Splutterwit used the same way. Otherwise, it's impossible to get his and my solution.

Comment: @Eloise I posted a full solution for you.

Comment: Yeah, I see how you got there now. That was my only issue with your solution - it seemed like you just plucked the two values of $a$ and $b$ out of a hat. But OP wouldn't be able to get those values without first working through in a way like you or Donald did (or using calculus). I think we can all agree that using calculus makes this problem a fair bit easier!

Comment: @T. Linnell I did not use calculus here. Just my technique is very  good. Sometimes human don't understand this point.

Answer (score 3):

$$(a-b)^2 + (2-a-b)^2 + (2a-3b)^2 = \left\| \,\, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1\\ 2 & -3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 2\\ 0\end{bmatrix} \,\, \right\|_2^2$$

This is a **least-squares** problem. Since the matrix has full column rank, the **minimum** is

$$\left\| \,\, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1\\ 2 & -3\end{bmatrix} \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1\\ 2 & -3\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1\\ 2 & -3\end{bmatrix} \right)^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1\\ 2 & -3\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 2\\ 0\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 2\\ 0\end{bmatrix} \,\, \right\|_2^2 = \color{blue}{\frac{2}{15}}$$

---

**SymPy code**

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> A = Matrix([[ 1,-1],
                [ 1, 1],
                [ 2,-3]])
>>> b = Matrix([0,2,0])
>>> error = A * (A.T * A)**-1 * A.T * b - b
```

The squared Euclidean norm of the error vector is

```
>>> error.T * error
Matrix([[2/15]])
```